# Joomla installation on localhost using WAMP does not start

Tags: joomla-3.x

Joomla installation/Joomla website on localhost using WAMP does not start. No error is reported in the logs file. I'm using 

Windows 10 
WAMP 3.1.4 (64 Bit)
Apache 2.4.35 Port 80- PHP 7.2.10
MySQL 5.7.14 Port 3306
MariaDB 10.3.9 Port 3307
Joomla 3.9.14 & Joomla 3.9.13 (used both but same results)
Chrome 83+
Firefox 77+

Comment: Is your wamp icon in the taskbar green? And what do you mean by "does not start"?

Comment: Yes it was green and online, by "does not start" I meant that I entered the url of the Joomla it showed me ;

**The site can't be reached**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue, upon debugging I found that port 80 was being used by another instance of httpd.exe, two  instance of httpd.exe were running which was causing the issue. **I resolved it by Using port 8080 instead of 80**.

Comment: WAMP on OSX? OSX has its own httpd daemon running, but this is easily solved by setting the WAMP port and user:group WAMP apache runs as.

Comment: I am using Windows 10.

Comment: I am happy to see that you have resolved your issue.  As a matter of tidying up this page, please edit your question to contain the additional clues that you discovered.  The question should contain ALL of the diagnostic details; the answer should state what was done to resolve the issue (and why the solution works -- when known). A complete question will be more likely to gather upvotes and invite high quality answers.